# Foundation Modal Showing Background

Tags: modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, fullscreen

Using Zurb Foundation and have several full-screen modals. Works great on desktop, but they are not taking up full screen on mobile. Shows the top bar behind modal and pushes it down. Can be seen when one clicks any of the "more" buttons [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3MPN.jpg).

I've seen this issue on other forums. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I have added screen shots from my site as well as the foundation documentation page, both showing the same problem. One can interact with the background in a full-screen modal.

[Screenshot after clicking menu icon in background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3MPN.jpg)

[Screenshot showing same problem on Zurb Foundation doc page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2hKI.jpg)

[Screenshot showing same issue on iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEqE3.jpg)

Comment: I was unable to see the issue when using Chrome's responsive mode.  Does this only show up on actual devices?

Comment: @tephyr yes it seems to only happen on actual devices. It also happens in the example full screen modal on the Foundation documentation page.

Comment: I cannot repro with Firefox on Android on either Zurb's site or yours.  Some screenshots & browser info may be helpful.

Comment: @tephyr I have edited to show screenshots. This is on Android Chrome v58.0.3029.83

Comment: This looks like a bug in Foundation, and should be reported to them.